# Why does my code only return partial results? array_push not working for first element

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

So I'm returning an array of arrays returned from an MySQLi query, as you can see it pulls distinct categories from my layers database and then returns each layer associated with that category.

The results are only returning some results and not all when the code using print_r returns all the layers.

Where am I going wrong?

https://api.adameastwood.com/v1/TEST/logger.php -> results of print_r and foreach loop

```
$conn = new mysqli($sqlParams['host'], $sqlParams['username'], 
$sqlParams['password'], $sqlParams['database']);
$Query = "SELECT DISTINCT `Category` FROM `layers` WHERE `enabled` = 1 
ORDER BY `Category` ASC";
$menuCategories = [];

if ($result = $conn->query($Query))
{                   
while ($categoryRow = $result->fetch_row()){
    foreach($categoryRow as $key => $value)
    {           
        $layers = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `layers` WHERE enabled = 1 AND Category = '$value' ORDER  BY LayerName ASC");

        while ($layerDetails = $layers->fetch_array()){

            $menuItems = array([
                'LCategory' => $layerDetails['Category'],
                'LayerCode' => $layerDetails['LayerCode'], 
                'LayerName' => $layerDetails['LayerName'],
            ]);

            foreach($menuItems as $item){
                print_r($item);

                $item = array('LayerDetails' => $item);
                array_push($menuCategories['menuItem'][$value], $item);

                foreach($item as $items => $itemValue)
                    array_push($menuCategories['menuItem'][$value][$itemValue], $itemValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "\n\n";

Array
(
    [LCategory] => Council Assets
    [LayerCode] => RBC/AL
    [LayerName] => Available Land
)
Array
(
    [LCategory] => Council Assets
    [LayerCode] => RBC/COL
    [LayerName] => Council Owned Land
)
Array
(
    [LCategory] => Planning
    [LayerCode] => DC/CA
    [LayerName] => Conservation Areas
)
Array
(
    [LCategory] => Planning
    [LayerCode] => DC/LB
    [LayerName] => Listed Buildings
)
Array
(
    [LCategory] => Planning
    [LayerCode] => DC/PA
    [LayerName] => Planning Applications
)
Array
(
    [LCategory] => Planning
    [LayerCode] => DC/TPO
    [LayerName] => Tree Preservation Orders
)


{
    "menuItem": {
        "Council Assets": [
            {
            "LayerDetails": {
                "LCategory": "Council Assets",
                "LayerCode": "RBC\/COL",
                "LayerName": "Council Owned Land"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Planning": [
        {
            "LayerDetails": {
                "LCategory": "Planning",
                "LayerCode": "DC\/LB",
                "LayerName": "Listed Buildings"
            }
        },
        {
            "LayerDetails": {
                "LCategory": "Planning",
                "LayerCode": "DC\/PA",
                "LayerName": "Planning Applications"
            }
        },
        {
            "LayerDetails": {
                "LCategory": "Planning",
                "LayerCode": "DC\/TPO",
                "LayerName": "Tree Preservation Orders"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Could you also tell us what is the expected outcome? Your code is overly complicated and I am having trouble understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi Dharman, I am trying to parse the array '$item' into JSON but organise the results into separate arrays categorised by 'LCategory'

Comment: You should be able to turn your SQL into a single query.

Comment: I think that there should be `$items` instead of `$itemValue` in this line:  `$menuCategories['menuItem'][$value][$itemValue]`

Comment: When you define `menuItems` you use double array - both `array` and `[]` - why? This cause to yuor for loop of `foreach($menuItems as $item)` to run only once

Comment: @Dharman, when I used $items it adds a weird tag to the JSON that I don't want.

Comment: @David, if I don't use Array([]) then it adds every value to a new array instead of a single one

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to get. Reduce the number of loops and intermediate arrays.

Comment: Also, you redefine `$item` to be single element array. so when you do `foreach($item as $items => $itemValue)` then `itemValue` is actually an array...
Can you please give us your desire output?

Comment: @DavidWinder this is what I pointed out before, but why is he looping on it again?

Comment: @AdamEastwood Did my post helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lot of "not-good-practice" behavior - but let address your issue:

Notice that [array-push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) raise warning when null is given and not array (and you never init empty array in key `menuItem` or the category names). However, it does create an array after the command is sent - therefor, only the first element is left out.

Change you `array_push` to `[]` as `$menuCategories['menuItem'][$value][] =  $item;` to make it work as you intend (change both `array_push`)